# Migrating Wordpress data from one website to another

Tags: wordpress, web, themes, migrate

**Edit: Editing the original post to make my question simpler**

My friend has a art website which is made in wordpress www..com. He hired a wordpress expert to redesign the website. The expert made the redesign at another location at www..com/ so both the websites are at different locations. I have to take the look of the redesigned site and the data of the mainwebsite, what approach should I take. The redsigned website should have all the plugins which are there in the mainwebsite. The redesigned website will replace the mainwebsite.

In short what approach should I take to migrate the new website design to actual website.

Any suggestions and inputs will be appreciated.

**Update:**

Thanks to everyone for taking time for answering the question, all of the answers are right in one way or the other, I would like to share this resource which I found extremely useful that I have bookmarked it for future reference, the author has explained all scenarios to migrate WordPress website. Hope you find it useful. The link to the website is http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/08/moving-wordpress-website/
I am no way related to this author or website, I am sharing this to help anyone who faces similar problem that I faced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Export the MySQL database from the current site.
2. Restore the database backup on the new server.
3. Copy the entire website to your machine via FTP.
4. Edit wp-config.php to point to the new database. If
   you are changing domains, then see the link below.
5. Copy the site files to the new hosting server via FTP.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 0):

go to tools->import
now select wordpress and install the plugin
now you can export all your posts/pages and use the same tool to import that data to your new site

Comment: Actually the redesigned website will replace the actual website. So what approach should I take.

Comment: i guess you don't have any data in your new site that has to be included in your mainsite, you just want the design. is that correct??

If that's the case then you can simply copy and replace your theme new designed theme folder in your existing mainsite's theme folder and apply that theme from dashboard.

(Make sure to backup the existing theme incase anything goes wrong :p )

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following steps

- Create a dummy site (beta or temp)
- Move current mainsite there
- Download theme from the redesigned site
- Install it on the dummy site
- Make sure everything is working perfectly as you want with the data you want
- Move it live

Hope this helps.